# JavaFX Node partial border

Tags: java, css, javafx, border

Having a Node for example VBox I am trying to add a border and there are 2 ways I can think of - using css or using new Border () etc..

How can I remove part of the border ? i.e remove the bottom part of the border

Comment: If you want to remove the bottom part of the border, use: border-bottom: none;

Comment: This should be CSS right ?

Comment: Yes it would be CSS.

Comment: i will give it a try

Comment: @Leon: In JavaFX css does not provide the same set of properties as in html. `border-bottom` won't work.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specify different styles for the borders on different sides

#### Using Border

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Region root = new Region();
    root.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.RED,
            BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, BorderStrokeStyle.NONE, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,
            CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(5), Insets.EMPTY)));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### Using inline css

```
root.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid solid none solid; -fx-border-width: 5; -fx-border-color: red;");
```

#### Using a css stylesheet

```css
.root { /* modify the selector according to your needs */
    -fx-border-style: solid solid none solid;
    -fx-border-width: 5;
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

**`none`** doesnt work on javafx 13. I tried changing it to `hidden` and it worked.

```
.root { /* modify the selector according to your needs */
    -fx-border-style: solid solid hidden solid;
    -fx-border-width: 5;
    -fx-border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hidden seems to still use the space of the border

Comment: Both hidden and none didn't work - JavaFX 17. Looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Setting border-width to 0 worked (JavaFX 17): Example:

```
#header
{
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-style: solid;
}
```

Here you can get border only at bottom - order: Top, right, bottom, left.